# How to get the "dashboard" ripple-effect and closing-effect for UIViews?

Tags: uiview, core-animation, dashboard

My project add a UIView with a button press. Is it possible to get the dashboard ripple-effect when the subview is added to the view?
Also the subview can be closed with: `removeFromSuperview`. How can I get the closing effect of a dashboard widget (when you press on the x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: The ripple effect is undocumented so you can't use it in AppStore.

---

As of 3.1.2, you can use a ripple transition effect with

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"transition" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:110 forView:myViewContainer cache:YES];
// add subview here.
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: wow! nice. where did you find all the undocumented transitions?

Comment: Quick question for an old post, as this is undocumented, is this app store safe?

Comment: @scorpiozj, Oriacle: It is written clearly in the first sentence!